# cmd.exe through C#: Interactive commands

Tags: .net, process, cmd, system.diagnostics

I have to execute some commands in `cmd.exe`, and it works well, but interactive commands do not work. For example, when executing `sc` in a normal `cmd.exe` window, at the end of the output you get:

```
Would you like to see help for the QUERY and QUERYEX commands? [ y | n ]:
```

And if you press `y` you get more output. Well, when executing this from C# I am unable of passing through commands like this. Even sending a `y` character does not make the screen progress, it gets stuck there forever.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = "C:\\"
    }
};

proc.Start();
Task.Run(() => ShowInConsoleAsync(proc.StandardOutput));
Task.Run(() => ShowInConsoleAsync(proc.StandardError));

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("sc");
proc.StandardInput.Flush();

Thread.Sleep(1000);

proc.StandardInput.Write("y");
proc.StandardInput.Flush();

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

But it gets stuck at this line:

```
Would you like to see help for the QUERY and QUERYEX commands? [ y | n ]:
```

Any idea?

Comment: What about using powershell instead of cmd.exe? It is a lot easier to run custom code in a powershell script.

Comment: Sure, but I would like to know how to solve this.

Comment: Use Tools + Attach to Process and select sc.exe while it is showing that prompt.  You'll see it called _getch().  The .NET equivalent is Console.ReadKey().  Not redirected, you can't fix this.

Comment: I put it in WinDbg and got ReadConsoleInputA. `The low-level console I/O functions expand an application's control over console I/O by enabling direct access to a console's input and screen buffers.`

Comment: Try Sendkeys. .NET have that? VB.NET will. VBScript also.

Comment: It seems to be part of `System.Windows.Forms`, I will take a look.